# Hiding content to prevent cheating in JavaScript-made game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, hide, secure-coding

I know it's impossible to completely prevent users from cheating and/or cracking a web application, but this hole I found is so easy to find that it really should be plugged up.

https://mcthompsonatl.github.io/

I didn't actually code any of this. I was given this very basic "find all 6 objects" (in this case, keys) guessing game that a former employee, who wasn't a programmer by trade, wrote for a promotion for one of our clients. The logic is sound, and it needs some formatting work, but while testing it out in developer mode, it took me very little time to find that the game can easily be won just by inspecting each `<div>` of the `card` class. Because this is being used for a promotional contest, I've been trying to figure out a way to either hide or change the game-breaking code to where inspecting any of the cards in developer mode doesn't reveal any hints.

The one solution I could find was to change the card elements to multiple HTML5 Canvas elements. The two problems with that is 1. I have zero experience working with Canvas and 2. Even if I did, it seems to be an extremely long and painful task, and I'm not sure if I'll be allowed the time I'd need to learn just enough to remedy the problem. Is this something that can be hidden with PHP? I'm a bit stumped here finding a sensible solution. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I suggest making a remote procedure call every time the user interacts with a card, either with ajax or over websockets. There's nothing preventing users from inspecting client side code; so keep that information server side until it's needed.

Comment: Currently your game is similar to a scratch-off lottery ticket where the actual values are predetermined yet hidden.  Ideally you'll do something like @DaveSnyder recommends, a click generates a call to a server which tells you what's behind the card, and then you display it.  However a more basic js-only approach might be to give each clicked square a percent chance to have a winner behind it which is not determined til it's clicked.  That has its own flaws, because reporting a win to the server is still easily spoofable (bypassing the game entirely).

Comment: Are you using jquery? I'm working on something and want to know if you using so I can use it in my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Too long for a comment.*

Based on what I understood from the game. You have 36 boxes, you need to click on random boxes. If you click on the X number of the correct boxes, you win.

I was able to cheat by inspecting the HTML and searching for the image that indicates the winning key. The image name was `images/keytowin/frontImage.png`

A solution may be to not pre-assign the image that indicates "correct" choice to the HTML div. Rather, assign the image only after it's being clicked. This will make it harder to find since the HTML alone won't give it away.

The idea y here is `Random`. Using Javascript, generate 3 random number between 1 and 36. These three random numbers indicate the winning boxes. If the user clicks on a box, and it has the same number (I noticed the `div` are numbered `data-id="1"` ) then use JS to add an image the inner div on the fly.

The three random numbers, however, will be determined when the game starts. Therefore, obscuring the variables is important.

I have provided a sample code to demonstrate the concept.

```js
var luckyNumbers = getUniqueNumbers();
var winImg = "<img  src='https://mcthompsonatl.github.io/images/keytowin/frontImage.png' alt='X LOGO'>";
var loseImg = "<img  src='https://mcthompsonatl.github.io/images/keytowin/TryAgain.png' alt='X LOGO'>";

console.log(luckyNumbers);

$(".card").on("click", function() {

  if (!$(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
    $(this).addClass("clicked");

    selected = Number($(this).attr("data-id"));
    if (luckyNumbers.indexOf(selected) > -1) {
      //code to put a key image     
      $(this).find(".back").append(winImg);
    } else {
      console.log("wrong: " + selected);
      //code to put not-winning image     
      $(this).find(".back").append(loseImg);
    }

  }

});



function getUniqueNumbers() {
  var arr = []
  while (arr.length < 3) {
    var someRand = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 36)
    if (arr.indexOf(someRand) > -1) continue;
    arr[arr.length] = someRand;
  }
  return arr;
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width" name="viewport">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="game">


    <div class="card" data-id="5">
      <div class="inside">
        <div class="front">
          <img src="image/someimage.jpg" alt="keytowin">
        </div>
        <div class="back">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card" data-id="6">
      <div class="inside">
        <div class="front">
          <img src="image/someimage.jpg" alt="keytowin">
        </div>
        <div class="back">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="card" data-id="7">
      <div class="inside">
        <div class="front">
          <img src="image/someimage.jpg" alt="keytowin">
        </div>
        <div class="back">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js">
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, sorry I'm just getting around to this, but this project has been put on the backburner (not my call). However, I'm planning on a personal project for a memory match game that is pretty similar, and it seems to be a pretty good solution.

Comment: @mthomp81 this kind of stuff interests me actually. Do you want to work on it together?